# Skobbler get roundabout exit

Tags: android, navigation, skmaps

I want to find the exit number (for example second exit) for a roundabout during navigation from `SKNavigationState` during turn-by-turn navigation.

I've looked at the docs but I can't find a way of finding it through the Android SDK.

I've tried [`SKNavigationState.getCurrentAdviceExitNumber()`](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/com/skobbler/ngx/navigation/SKNavigationState.html#getCurrentAdviceExitNumber()) does not return anything.

I'm also trying to parse `SKNavigationState.getAdviceInstruction()` for an exit number but this doesn't seem like the best way.

Is there a way to do this? How can I get the exit number for a roundabout?

Comment: See http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/com/skobbler/ngx/routing/SKRouteAdvice.SKStreetDirection.html#DIRECTION_ROUNDABOUT

Answer (score 1):

Currently this information is not exposed via an API.

The only way of retrieving this information would be to parse the text instruction that is provided (as there you have a "exit number parameter").

See http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-scout-audio/ for details

You can do this both when using prerecorded audio or text-to-speech (TTS) - some regular expression text parsing should do the job (I guess that using the prerecorded audio will be easier as the generated text instruction is more "computer like")